# Cypher query with variable length path and constraints on labels + link properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm a newbie in Cypher and Graph DB...I am trying to display a kind of tree from my DB, with a source node, and the downstream leaves. I would like to filter on only the leaves that have only certain labels and where all the relationships have a specific constraint on their properties.
Root is a **Column1** and I want to arrive on a **Column1** as well, but there can be some **Column2** in the path

I wrote this:

```
MATCH p=(:Column1{name:'Root'})-[*1..7]-(:Column1) 
WHERE 
    all(n IN nodes(p) 
        WHERE all(l in labels(n) 
                WHERE l IN ['Column1', 'Column2']
                )
        AND n.deleted='0'
        ) 
    AND all(r IN relationships(p) 
            WHERE r.deleted='0')
 RETURN p
```

When launched in Neo4J browser, the resulting graph is wrong and includes some relationships where **deleted='1'**. However, if I export the CSV table and look for deleted='1' (or even just 1), there are no result.

So it seems like the query is correct, but somehow, the graphical display will show the relationships where deleted=1.

Is it a bug, is it the query?

I also tried

```
MATCH (:Column1{name:'Root'})-[*1..7{deleted:'0'}]-(t)
WHERE t:Column1 or t:Column2
RETURN *
```

but in my DB, it takes forever to complete, compared to the previous query.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I had to uncheck the "Connect Result nodes" check box in the config tab of the browser. Otherwise, it queries for all the relationships between the displayed node!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
MATCH (:Column1 {name: 'Root'})-[*1..7 {deleted: '0'}]-(t)
WHERE labels(t)[0] IN ['Column1', 'Column2']
RETURN *
```

Depending on the amount of nodes `Column1` has, and how many `Column1` exists in your db, I wouldn't recommend this approach without a `LIMIT 50` or whatever limit you want. If you do

```
PROFILE
MATCH (:Column1 {name: 'Root'})-[*1..7 {deleted: '0'}]-(t)
WHERE labels(t)[0] IN ['Column1', 'Column2']
RETURN *
```

You'll see just how many db hits this makes which is really resource consuming.

Comment: In fact my second query is completely wrong since t represents the final node. So there could be any kind of column in between, using this query. The first query is the correct one regarding label filters. Btw, I solved the question. See my answer below. Thx.